# I am facing ParseException for French locale with SImpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, localization

I am getting ParseException with SimpleDateFormat in French locale.
There is a issue with other locale as well but I just debugged that for French. I am selecting date from UI calendar(say something like 01-Avr-2016, format "dd-MMM-yyyy") and when I pass this to my code:

```
String dateval = "01-Avr-2016";
Locale lformat = Locale.getDefault();
DateFormat specifiedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MMM-yyyy", lformat );
specifiedDateFormat.parse( dateval );
```

The above code is throwing error. I found that shortmonths in SimpleDateFormat come along with period(".") (for above example it would be "avr.") and I can write some logic to handle the period but I don't want to write any specific logic for French locale.
Instead I want to know why the month selected from calendar(coming from DateComponent) as "Avr" rather than "avr."? How can I handle that use case?

Comment: Please add some code with the calendar / DateComponent section of your question.  It's hard to say what's going on without seeing that piece.  The rest has been answered below.

Comment: down vote
accept
I have simple code of DateComponent.

protected DateComponent m_valueDateButton;
String dateString = m_valueDateButton.getDateViewModel().getDateString();
I am not sure, why period isn't coming along with French Date.

Answer (score 2):

So first off, your error comes from the fact that the `parse()` method throws a ParseException.  You need to handle it.

Secondly, in the French locale, shortened months are expected to be given with a period following the abbreviation.  If you can handle adding the period, you should have no issues.  As both "01-avr.-2016" and "01-Avr.-2016" are valid parseable dates.

There's a great related question about parsing French dates at [Parsing French Dates in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001478/parsing-french-dates-in-java)

```
String dateval = "01-avr.-2016";
Locale lformat = Locale.FRENCH;
DateFormat specifiedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MMM-yyyy", lformat );
try{
specifiedDateFormat.parse( dateval );
}
catch(ParseException pe){
    pe.printStackTrace();
    //or whatever logic you want to do on an invalid entry
}
```

For the case where you want to handle the "avr" or "Avr" directly, use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) as follows:

```
LocalDate frenchDate = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy").withLocale( Locale.FRENCH ).parseLocalDate("01-Avr-2016");
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Java 8` in `Date Time Api`, you can use this way,

```
// french date formatting (1. avril 2014)
String frenchDate = dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d. MMMM yyyy", new Locale("fr")));
```

For more:

1. http://www.mscharhag.com/java/java-8-date-time-api

The following table shows how dates are formatted for each style with the `French locales:`

[Sample Date Formats of French is given below](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormat.html)

```
Style   French Locale

DEFAULT 30 juin 2009

SHORT   30/06/09

MEDIUM  30 juin 2009

LONG    30 juin 2009

FULL    mardi 30 juin 2009
```

**Update:**

Use [DateFormat.getDateInstance(int style, Locale locale)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance(int,%20java.util.Locale)) instead of creating your own patterns with `SimpleDateFormat`.